# add to cart with custom price woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i use this action to add custom price to item with custom field input as `$_SESSION['wo_price_d_"product_id"'];` , but if the user add the item more than one to the cart with different price every time, the action hook overwrite the old item price and add the new one with +1 to quantity,

How can i let the user add the item more than one without overwrite the old?

woocommerce v3+

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $product_id =$value['data']->id;
        $price = $_SESSION['wo_price_d_'.$product_id];
        if($price){
            $value['data']->set_price($price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the custom price field in product page ?

Comment: no in category page